# What is the measure of any given section of this variant of the Sierpinski carpet? Relationship between p-adics and $\pi$.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, fractals

The Sierpinski carpet is a $1\times 1$ square with the centre $9^{th}$ removed, then the centre $9^{th}$ of the eight remaining disjoint squares removed, and so on $n$ times, with $n\to\infty$, as described here: [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SierpinskiCarpet.html)

If you take a section through a Sierpinski carpet half-way up you have the Cantor set; an infinite closed perfect set of zero measure.  In fact the square fractal's area is given by $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{8}{9})^n$ which appears to limit to $0$, implying the measure across at *any* height is zero.

If instead of repeatedly removing the central $9^{th}$, we first remove the central $9^{th}$, then remove the centre $25^{th}$ of the $8$ remaining smaller squares. Then remove the centre $49^{th}$ of the remaining $96$ smaller still squares, and so on, then the area remaining is given by half of the [Wallis Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product): $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^2-1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Edd Pegg describes this [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/822984)

> What is the Lebesgue measure $\lambda(y)$ of a horizontal section through this set as a function of $y$, the height from the baseline at which the section is taken?

For the original Sierpinski carpet the measure of any section looks to be closely related to the 2-adic metric of $y$, provided we don't take $n$ to infinity.

For the pi-carpet (let's call it) it looks to be *something like* half of the length of a chord across a circle, taken at the $(2n+1)$-adic metric distance from the circle's widest point.  The reason I say this is that every width of a circle is still represented, they are just ordered by some metric similar to the $2$-adic but growing to $2n+1$ at each base step instead of $2n$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're modifying the standard Sierpinski carpet construction so that the sub-squares are divided into smaller and smaller parts at each step, as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM9Hu.png). In addition, you're also starting with a grid of four squares so that the result looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WHSl.png). Correct?

Comment: Actually, $$4\cdot\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2-1}{n}=0$$

Comment: Even if you start at $n = 2$ to avoid the problem that Did has spotted, that product clearly diverges.

Comment: @PaulSinclair sorry typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @MarkMcClure yes, and asking for a closed form for the Lebesque measure of the width at any given height.  I think this function should induce a metric space with some interesting properties, like a p-adic but independent of any individual prime number. A pi-adic you might call it.

Comment: @Did I think I fixed the formula now.